# Remove beta profile without wiping phone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I participated in the iOS 10 beta, and now that it's release is imminent, I'd like to remove the profile and continue on with regular public releases, but I'd like to not have to wipe my phone. Is this possible at all? Looking at Apple's site, it states to put the phone into recovery mode, but I've always sort of associated that with wiping the phone.

Comment: You can just remove the beta profile.

Comment: I think, correct me if I'm wrong, when the update is released, you can just do an in-place update and not have to wipe your data.  I don't recall ever wiping my iPhone when moving from the beta to the release.

Answer (score 1):

You can also connect your iPhone to a Mac and use Apple Configurator 2 to remove the profile:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the final iOS 10 update comes out. Update to that version of iOS 10, then you can safely remove the beta profile from your phone without restoring. If you don't wants to wait, you have two options:

1. Go to [ipsw.me](http://ipsw.me) and find the iOS 9.3.5 IPSW for your iPhone. Then connect iPhone to iTunes, option-click (shift-click on Windows) Check for Update, select the IPSW and downgrade to 9.3.5. Then remove the profile.
2. If you don't care about some bugs, you can just remove it and stay on that beta. When iOS 10 comes out, you will receive that update.

Still if you really wants to make sure that you fully removed it, you should restore the phone.